# LENOVO Thinkpad Carbon X1 Gen8: how to use the 3.5 mm TRRS jack as stereo line in?

Tags: laptop, audio, thinkpad, microphone, headphones

## Situation

I've got a **Lenovo Thinkpad Carbon X1 Gen8 (Model *2OU9 - 0006GE*)** here, which features a 3.5 mm **[TRRS](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3b/3.5mm.jpg/1280px-3.5mm.jpg)** headphone/mic combo jack.
I'd like to plug a 3.5 mm **[TRS](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/16/TRS_connector.JPG/800px-TRS_connector.JPG)** stereo *line in* cable from my analog mixer into this jack, in order to record the audio signal with the laptop.

However, the Thinkpad insists on recognizing any **[TRS](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/16/TRS_connector.JPG/800px-TRS_connector.JPG)** cables as a pair of headphones and won't allow me to change this from output to input anywhere.

On the Dell laptops I've used so far, there was this "Which device did you plug in?" prompt shown below, which gives me the option to select *line in* instead of *headphone* and record audio from a **[TRS](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/16/TRS_connector.JPG/800px-TRS_connector.JPG)** cable plugged into the **[TRRS](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3b/3.5mm.jpg/1280px-3.5mm.jpg)** jack.

[image: Dell Precision 7510 TRRS input prompt]

## Question

### Is there any way of getting the Dell-style "Which device did you plug in?" prompt on the Thinkpad Carbon X1 Gen8 as well?

I wouldn't mind using third party software to achive this.
**I know that you can use a [hardware TRRS-Y-Splitter](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/images/images2000x2000/sabrent_cb_auhm_3_5mm_aux_male_to_1427143.jpg) and this is what I'm already successfully using.** However, it will only give me a mono signal and the noise levels of these splitters is significantly higher than when I can plug the **[TRS](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/16/TRS_connector.JPG/800px-TRS_connector.JPG)** cable directly into the machine.